# Is an event fired when an HTML import finishes loading?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, custom-element, html-imports

So I am loading a load screen in my app. Then I load my custom elements through HTML imports by making a `link` element in JavaScript. I need to know when this HTML import has finished loading to display content to the user. Do HTML imports fire an event when the download finishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `onload` event.

```
<script async>
  function handleLoad(e) {
    console.log('Loaded import: ' + e.target.href);
  }
  function handleError(e) {
    console.log('Error loading import: ' + e.target.href);
  }
</script>

<link rel="import" href="file.html"
      onload="handleLoad(event)" onerror="handleError(event)">
```

For more on imports, [here you go](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/).

Answer (score 3):

When the HTML import has finished loading, it fires an event called **HTMLImportsLoaded**. I'd recommend you to rely on this event to get a consistant behavior across the different browsers.

```
window.addEventListener( "HTMLImportsLoaded", function ()
{
    //HTML Imports are loaded
} )
```

On HTML Imports, read this to understand the difference between `onload`, `HTMLImportsLoaded` and `WebComponentsReady` :
http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/html-imports/

Answer (score 2):

If you need to know when all imports are loaded you can use:

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    // imports are loaded and elements have been registered
  });
```

Comment: Will it work fine if I create a new <link> element and appen to <head> after the event has been fired once already?I intend to load a <loadscreen> element and then load all elements after that using javascript.

Comment: In this situation probably is more suitable to use "onload="handleLoad(event)"  for  <loadscreen > import and here to load rest of your components. 'WebComponentsReady' event possible to work also if you only import loadscreen element and in  'WebComponentsReady' handler load rest of your components.I suggest to place all imports (except import for loadscreen) in a single html and load that html after <loadscreen> is imported.